# Oracle stored procedure to SQL Server conversion: SYS.SCHEDULER_FILEWATCHER_RESULT

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I am migrating an Oracle stored procedure to SQL Server but I'm unable to find any compatible solution for the below code specially with `SYS.SCHEDULER_FILEWATCHER_RESULT` passed as a parameter.

```
PROCEDURE prc_file_wtchr_load (p_sfwr IN SYS.SCHEDULER_FILEWATCHER_RESULT)
IS
  --Define Constants--
  v_name   CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (30) := 'Test';
  
//Some code
//

END prc_file_wtchr_load;
```

Seems like need to create some task in SQL Server but unable find any solution over the internet. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing built-in to either SQL Server itself or Agent that replicates this functionality (being able to trigger a job on the appearance of a file). You will need to write client code for this.

Comment: You can put a trigger on a File Table that will fire any time a new file is added to the associated share.